# Is it possible to reference an implementing type in an abstract class method type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class `Thingydoo`, and a class `Thingymabob` that extends it. I have some static methods on `Thingydoo` that I want to create something of a type that exists in `Thingymabob`. The underlying reason I'm trying to do this is in order to give an API for different types of `Thingydoo` to be created with different options for each of them programmatically.

```
interface MyStuff {
    [name: string]: {someParam: string}
};

type Something<T> = {
    thing: T;
}

abstract class Thingydoo {
    //                  here - on this line - TypeScript uses "this" to mean Thingydoo, not the Thingymabob that comes from it
    static testWithTypeParam(thing: ReturnType<typeof this.differentFunc>): Something<ReturnType<typeof this.differentFunc>> {
        // here, in this line, TypeScript _knows_ that this.name is Thingymabob, not Thingydoo.
        console.log("hi! this is a " + this.name);
        return {thing: thing};
    }

    static differentFunc() : MyStuff {
        return {};
    }
}

class Thingymabob extends Thingydoo {
    static differentFunc(): {beans: {someParam: string}} {
        return {beans: {someParam: "test"}};
    }

    static feedMeBeans(beansContainer: {beans: {someParam: string}}) {
        console.log(beansContainer.beans.someParam);
    }
}

let something = Thingymabob.testWithTypeParam({beans: {someParam: "test3"}});
// so this, despite making sense and compiling to JS fine + running fine in JS, issues a compiler error in tsc, because it doesn't realise the beans type is MyStuff compatible.
Thingymabob.feedMeBeans(something.thing);
```

In this example, I want `testWithTypeParam` to return an object of type `{beans: {someParam: string}}`, so as to be compatible with the `feedMeBeans` method on `Thingymabob`. This doesn't seem to want to be possible at all, though: I can't find a way of doing it. I've tried using the polymorphic `this` types, as shown in the example code, but have made no headway at all with that route: it seems to make absolutely no difference [(playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKYCuMbIDeAUMmcgNohwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmAuo4UwPZ0ACnCi1GLNiHYBfYtIDcxYmHQAHFJgEQwACw4AeACoA+ZAF4ipcro6NDi2cTgAjCYjDIEAGzhMmyQz0pdAATPj5LcmQAemio+ITyHWgUAFpkPhBkG38vUDSAtQhMBDZVDxwmCH8AIhya7Ii6OCzAjlDwgBpkED4PXRQ24JoXPmdsnTgPBC1-GCgBZGAwKzIWKeAEbOqwAHVlnUMi4VEaI2QIAA9IEBD-FXU+AiH2Dr5jAAocu26bKUYAEraHBQEBHdT6B4QJ4TYBMAB0IWA+BS4AAYjgQAhjABKRiaOh-dj6IG4UHgiCQoownKI5EwVFgDFY4ymEiJGJxZJQCDdUCw3L5boUkplDwAfQA1r0AO5McUTKYC+HUOhLfwvdAjZxjbq9DyasJ8eGreIzED8LwQeFePjsD41PQAQgF6uQcGQDQA1MrVRAcYoOTyyVlCETGESFKbHFF1mBNsgkSieejMQgPjjkIwMNg8AR2YlgyDQ1GorJHN5fBqgq9tWMLtcILdq+0jZFyHGE0mGSmmWmMzxnBAWkwePwhCIxMxWBxpNJ2wki6CiEOR2OtCcp3UdjU54HyDGO2ANlsGRAQqgIAAhYcWj6ri0AYUyx-yUEHt9HRHHEE3NHEM5SHOmYFgk5qWtatr2g+TDPuAcBvvCMHwj+f4BtGchKFaHg-kS5gBDWWqjM48KQCw+y6BSf4fIQMHrhOpyMNuLAAMy7tI6GxMwEQ5N0ITVKoywoCMkocMwTZVO6tyeAIgl5FIjTIAAUpgyAwPkyA+lAmIgGJ6kgCg-IqXyfg4NU7oyTQcnQBcUALFASxZGATAIN0Q4IHAlSGR4YTVCAADkHg8nAeSSQMyAwdkRRujmuD4JZqgbM4VompqdYkWeF7Xp+Hy4TWpE1gGQA).

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have a good concept for "static `this`", which is presumably why you went through the trouble of making the methods generic in the playground link.  But you didn't quite follow through (`T` takes the place of `this`).  If you do you get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wO5qEm) which I think works as you want. Shall I write this up as an answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz - thanks, that does solve the original problem as stated! My MRE was slightly off from my actual problem I think though - I've now essentially come across [this problem](https://tsplay.dev/w1xY8W), where this.differentFunc() references the abstract class and not the implementor. I could try `return { thing: this.differentFunc() as unknown as T["differentFunc"]};`, and I think technically that _would_ work, but it feels very wrong!

Comment: That's an independent issue described at [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912); `ReturnType` is a conditional type and if you pass it something that depends on a generic type like `T` (and even `this` is "implicitly" generic) then the compiler can' do much to verify assignability. You could completely refactor to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKve8m) but it seems off-topic here. Can I just answer your question as asked and then if you want to talk about this other issue further you can open an new question? Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz - absolutely, thank you very much! happy to mark as answered, you've been extremely helpful :)

Comment: Okay I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't directly support the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) for `static` members.  There's a longstanding open feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), but it hasn't been implemented (yet?).  Until and unless that happens you'll have to work around it.

For static *methods* a common workaround is to make the method [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a type `T` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to some supertype of what you want `this` to be (it might be `typeof Foo` if your class name is `Foo`, but it doesn't have to be), and then give the method a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) of type `T`.  And then (in this might be the part you were missing) you use the type `T` in place of the type `this`.  So instead of

```
class Foo { 
  ⋯
  static method(arg: A<this>): R<this> {⋯} 
  ⋯
}
```

you'd have

```
class Foo { 
  ⋯
  static method<T extends typeof Foo>(this: T, arg: F<T>): R<T> {⋯} 
  ⋯
}
```

For your code that looks like

```
abstract class Thingydoo {
    
    static testWithTypeParam<T extends typeof Thingydoo>(
        this: T, thing: ReturnType<T["differentFunc"]>
    ): Something<ReturnType<T["differentFunc"]>> {
        console.log("hi! this is a " + this.name);
        return { thing: thing };
    }

    static differentFunc(): MyStuff {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Note that `T` is a type, not a value, so you can't write `typeof T.differentFunc`. Instead you want "the type of the property of `T` whose key is `"differentFunc"`", which you get via the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T["differentFunc"]`.

And now it works as desired:

```
let something = Thingymabob.testWithTypeParam({ beans: { someParam: "test3" } });
// let something: Something<{ beans: { someParam: string; }; }>
Thingymabob.feedMeBeans(something.thing); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKYCuMbIDeAUMmcgNohwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmAuo4cwPZ0ACnCi1GLNiHbIAvsRkBuYsTDoADikwCIYABYcAPABUAfMgC8RUuT0dGRpXOJwARhMRhkCADZwmTZCN9KXQAEz4+K2syFjgwYARkSBYAdWA9I3UIYVEaY2QIAA9IEFCA1Q0+AiCOMIiTAApo8jJbJnsAGiTg9kYAJR0cKBBMjWMKACJQ4HxoCHAAMRwQBAnOE2aASkYtOlspAwHcYdGIcamZmDnF5dX1sxIWloQ+ECY+bwgAOm8+dgaJvoAITdYABMHIODICbIADUoKYX2odE2Sie5Cgg2GRFBUkY+2kimaThasXiiWms0xNxWDW2aCwuHwVnRZExxxARCJLTkTh8fgCNRCNFcfBcBWK8zKgR6dUij3IZISyEpV2pYCWtPpvBcEDgbx4-CEIjEzFYHFkloV6PZQ05Or1Bpx72NuUYE2SYBhMlkaPIJMVYDiyquEFCqAgACFHUwGrr9UwAMKvIOgaCG+NO3gu7Immjic1SS0yTYs1kvN4fb6-f6ZpMpuBpqBfOtfHM5Wio4nyZSfTw5gkWGW1EUuMVfT1pDJZDs0BoOhOG9t592egDM3tkXYA9NvkH2jToejttASDAus4fZwXJOwFL7ZBshex0KPx6Hw1GYw0Bz0Jz1UWQXdkD4ABrOB0GUIA)